# Reading source code of netty in trouble

Tags: netty

I am reading source code of Netty 4.0.10.Final.
In AbstractChannel.AbstractUnsafe class

```
    private void invokeLater(Runnable task) {
        // This method is used by outbound operation implementations to trigger an inbound event later.
        // They do not trigger an inbound event immediately because an outbound operation might have been
        // triggered by another inbound event handler method.  If fired immediately, the call stack
        // will look like this for example:
        //
        //   handlerA.inboundBufferUpdated() - (1) an inbound handler method closes a connection.
        //   -> handlerA.ctx.close()
        //      -> channel.unsafe.close()
        //         -> handlerA.channelInactive() - (2) another inbound handler method called while in (1) yet
        //
        // which means the execution of two inbound handler methods of the same handler overlap undesirably.
        eventLoop().execute(task);
    }
```

there comments puzzled me.
why outbound event trigger inbound event immediately.
somebody can explain details for me? thanks!

Comment: Is there a netty developer mailing list? That might be a better place to ask.

Comment: You got it:   https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/netty

Answer (score 1):

(I already answered this question, but I'm answering again to make this entry complete.)

What the comment says is basically we want to make sure the execution of the handler methods in the same handler doesn't overlap.  Without `invokeLater()`, `handlerA.channelInactive()` will be invoked even before `handlerA.inboundBufferUpdated()` returns.